# iPhone ad hoc build does not create a product

Tags: iphone, xcode, adhoc

I am trying to create an ad hoc build for my iPhone application. I followed the directions on the Provisioning Portal exactly, and I'm pretty sure my code signing is all correct, with the right provisioning profile and whatnot. The app builds fine under my Distribution configuration, I have set up Entitlements.plist correctly—everything seems in order.

However, after the build, no product appears. MyApp.app remains red in the product groups. Under, Build Settings for my target, the build product paths that are listed are never actually created. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here are all my build results messages, obviously trimmed down, but I don't think I've removed anything useful:

```
CpResource ...
ProcessInfoPlistFile ...
CompileXIB ...
...
CpResource ...
...
CopyPNGFile ...
...
CopyPlistFile ...
DataModelVersionCompile ...
ProcessPCH ...
...
CompileC ...
...
Ld ...
CreateUniversalBinary ...
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Xcode/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp -o /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM

ProcessProductPackaging "/Users/Jordan/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/0130341B-71DD-4808-AD90-D523F7574DAF.mobileprovision" /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> "/Users/Jordan/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/0130341B-71DD-4808-AD90-D523F7574DAF.mobileprovision" -o /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Touch /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app

ProcessProductPackaging Entitlements.plist /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.xcent
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    <com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects/Entitlements.plist -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.xcent

CodeSign /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Jordan Kay (3RTJV327L8)" --resource-rules=/Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.build/MyApp.xcent /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app

Validate /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app
    cd /Users/Jordan/Development/MyApp/trunk/Projects
    setenv PATH "/Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Xcode/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/Jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bceoakegbaymrjelqfmsvxnhjwna/Build/Products/Distribution-iphoneos/MyApp.app

2010-12-24 00:49:11.780 Validation[6437:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your **build results** here so we can take a look at it.

Edited: Issues are not sufficient. We need the entire results, **All Messages**. (See the new screenshot)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've updated the original post with this info. These warnings are all I'm seeing in Build Results.

Comment: I see, it looks like it's in some DerivedData folder in my user Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation is out of date currently. Set up everything like they say (which it seems you've done), then go to Build->Build and Archive. Then go to Window->Organizer. You should see your app under ARCHIVED APPLICATIONS (it's okay if an icon image doesn't show up). Click on it in the sidebar, click share, select your ad-hoc provisioning profile/certificate from the dropdown, then hit email or save to disk. Name it appname.ipa. Users can drag the ipa along with the provisioning profile into itunes and sync.

Comment: The old way of packaging the .app into a zip doesn't even work with the latest version of itunes/iOS, as far as I know.